# Browser back button makes user automatically log in again in Angular Js?

Tags: angularjs

I am working on, login module. In my case after user login and click logout button, then the user gets successfully logout, but after clicking on the browser back button user will get automatically logged in and I am using localStorage to store the user info and I am using $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess' but now it's working. So, can anyone tell me how to fix this problem ?

```js
var app= angular.module("angularTable", []);
app.controller("productController",  ['$rootScope', '$scope','$location', function($scope, $rootScope, $location)    {
     
     }]);


app.run(function($rootScope, $route, $location){
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
    $rootScope.actualLocation = $location.path();
  });        

  $rootScope.$watch(function () {return $location.path()}, function (newLocation, oldLocation) {
    if($rootScope.actualLocation === newLocation) {
        alert('Why did you use history back?');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Example using ui-state router plugin,

```
.run(function($window){

$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    var userLoggedIn = $window.localStorage.getItem('loggedIn');

    //user logged in and came to login then redirecting to dashboard
    if(toState.name == 'login' && userLoggedIn == true){
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('dashboard');
        return false;
    }

    //user logged out and taking user to login page (only current page is not login)
    if(userLoggedIn == false && toState.name != 'login'){
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login');
        return false;
    }

});
```

})